# Is there any better way of creating numpy array when number of elements are very high?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm reading the images (512 x 512) and corresponding labels, which were in .mat format, then  storing it into numpy array amd finally into .npy file....

```
i=0
arr1=[]
while(i<500):
    f=h5py.File(imagenames[i])
    dset=f['cjdata']
    print(i)
   a1=dset['image']
   a2=dset['label']
   arr1.append(np.array(a1))
   arr2.append(np.array(a2))
   np.save('xxtrain.npy',arr1)
np.save('yytrain.npy',arr2)
i=i+1
```

then I loaded  data1 and data2 with the values which were stored in the previous np file :

```
data1=np.load('xxtrain.npy')
data2=np.load('yytrain.npy')
```

Then, I printed the shape of each data1 and data2:

```
print(data1.shape)
print(data2.shape)
```

It printed as follows:

```
(500,)
(500, 1, 1)
```

The data2 shape is perfect , but the data1 shape should have been (500,512,512) it is considering data1 as one array of 500 elements ....

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you:)

Sorry for my English.

Comment: What's the dtype of the arrays?

Comment: In addition to what @hpaulj asked I would be interested also in the shape of a1 and a2.

Comment: I suspect `data1` has object dtype, and that it contains arrays that vary in shape.  In other words, your images are not all the same shape.  They may, for example all be 512x512, but some way be gray scale and some color (512,512,3).

Answer (score 0):

I'll edit my answer if you provide more info, but I think the problem is that you are trying to set every element of arr1 (a list) with a numpy array but np.save() doesn't know how to handle it. This could solve the problem:

```
i=0
arr1=np.zeroes((500, 512, 512))
while(i<500):
    f=h5py.File(imagenames[i])
    dset=f['cjdata']
    print(i)
    a1=dset['image']
    a2=dset['label']
    arr1[i,:,:] = np.array(a1)
    arr2.append(np.array(a2))
    np.save('xxtrain.npy',arr1)
    np.save('yytrain.npy',arr2)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: `arr1` is a list of arrays.  `np.save` will make an array from that list, and save that.  So what we get back from the load will the equivalent of `np.array(arr1)`.  If all `a1` are the same the result should be same as your `arr1`.  But I suspect his `a1` vary in shape, in which case your version would raise an error.

Comment: Some of the images are of different size, I came to know this when I executed my program with the above code. Also , this might be the reason that the shape of the data1 turned out to be (500,) previously because some of the images are 512 x 512 and some are of different size. can this be the reason ?

Comment: Resizing images to be the same size would be a fast fix. Otherwise you should rethink what you want to do with that piece of code and maybe change the save logic.